# Explanation regarding for loop

Tags: javascript

I have seen this usage of for loop in Java and also in Javascript. Logic dictates it is same in other C-like languages. This is JavaScript code:

```
function (startMove, endMove) {
    var accordionTempOrder;
    var that = this;

    var currentModelState = this.model.get('customentries'),
        temp = currentModelState[startMove]; //The last model to be applied
    if (startMove <= endMove) {
        for (var i = 1; i < endMove; i++) {
            if (i >= startMove) {
                source[i] = source[i + 1];
                source[i].ordinal--;                           
            }
        }
        source[endMove] = temp;

        //User dragged competitor box from bottom to top
    } else {
        for (; startMove > endMove; startMove--) {
            source[startMove] = source[startMove - 1];
            source[startMove].ordinal++;
        }
        source[endMove] = temp;
    }         
...
```

My question is what is the usage of ; in for loop? I need further explanation of this shorthand method. Is it just sugar coating? If someone can also provide another examples if the same methodology, that would be really appreciated. I like this shorthand, and would like to use it in my code as well, but I cant use something which I do not understand yet :)

Comment: I've removed the language tags except for javascript. Although, it is equivalent syntax, the usage can sometimes differ between languages which would result in confusing answers. In this case, I don't believe the answer would be any different - but then I don't use all that much javascript

Answer (score 2):

As per http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

the syntax of a `for`  block is

```
for (initialization; termination;
     increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

so if you do not need initialization, you can leave it blank, like-wise for other other sections

Answer (score 1):

All that means is that the loop is using an external variable to keep track of iterations. Meaning that there is no `int i = 0`.

You can actually leave all three parts out as all part are optional

```
for(;;)
```

and have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (; startMove > endMove; startMove--)
```

means the first parameter of the [for statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) (the initialization) is nothing.

In this case, `startMove` already has a value, no need to initialize anything more.

Comment: `for` is not a function. Not in JavaScript (the linked-to page even says "`for` statement" in the very beginning), and certainly not in C.

Answer (score 1):

*Well for me this image is enough to understand the for loop.*
[image]

[<sub>Image reference and for loop explanation</sub>](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/for)

As suggested in comment after considering it as a valid suggestion,Let me add some important points.

*for loop* has three major parts,

- Initialization part works only once and optional.
- Condition checked *for every iteration*.
- Modification(Increament/decrement) done *after* every iteration.

***But note*** one thing for infinite loop all three parts are optional.(i.e. `for( ; ;)`)

Comment: -1, having all the text of an answer in a non-searchable image is bad form in my opinion. Remember that even answers that *link to* textual answers are considered sub-optimal.

Answer (score 0):

A for loop statement has three parts: init, condition and "increment". In the case of your question there is no need for any initialization; nothing needs to be done before the loop, but the other two parts are still needed. The parts are separated by semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

first wikipedia result will give you this:

```
for(INITIALIZATION; CONDITION; INCREMENT/DECREMENT){
    // Code for the for loop's body
    // goes here.
}
```

any of the fields can be left empty if you dont need it.

the next line for example, means continue forever, because there is no stop condition.

```
for (var i = 1; ; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop for has a syntax

```
for(initialization; condition; increment/decrement/looping condition) {
  // CODE here
}
```

This is the syntax of the function in case you need not to use any of the above condition in the for loop you can just leave it blank.

for example we have

```
var itr = 0;
for(; itr<10; itr++) {
  // Do something
}
```

Here we did not require to initialize our variable itr since it was already initialized.

Another example

```
for(itr1=0,itr2=10; itr1<10;itr1++, itr2--) {
  // Do something
}
```

Here we initialized two variables in for loop itr1 and itr2, and incremented value of itr1 and decremented value of itr2